# Reinstall C++ Compiler for Simple Fast Multimedia Library (SFML)

Tags: c++, mingw, sfml

I need to install SFML for a project. According to the webpage (https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/) the compiler versions must match. However, my gcc version is 9.2.0, while the library is for GCC version 7.3.0. Hence, I was thinking of uninstalling MinGW 9.2.0 and install MinGW 7.3.0. But I can't seem to find the uninstall button in the MinGW Installer or Control Panel. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider instead installing an entire [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), such as [ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/). Backup your important data before trying

Comment: Any reason you can't build it yourself from source, using the compiler you have?

Comment: The [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) library is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source). Consider also compiling it from source code

Comment: Are there any online instructions you could point me to to help achieve this?

Comment: @Jen: you'll find such instructions quite easily. Look into the [source code repository](https://github.com/SFML/SFML). Alternatively, compile a fresh [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler from its source code